# Upload big files with laravel voyager admin panel not working

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I have this issue that I'm trying to upload files with more than 2MB. and it's not working.

I'm using both ways:

> 1. media picker with media manager
> 2. file input

and both has the same result.

I tried to change the PHP.ini with these:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

but nothing changed.

My files should be with type **`.exe || .apk`** and this is my second issue. how to add filter for these types from the admin panel.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well. I am getting "413 Request Entity Too Large" but I am unable to locate anything in the documentation or search engines that tell me the Voyager way of increasing the file upload limit size.

Comment: @SpencerHill can you please check which php.ini and check it's values ?! 
there is attribute in media picker can set the max limit in blade you need to override it .

Comment: After posting my comment I discovered Voyager relies on PHP.ini (https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/core-concepts/media-manager) and that I simply forgot to reboot NGinx and PHP for the change to take effect.